# convert $_POST values to CSV

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

Updated Situation:

I have managed to create a registration form that outputs the data to a new CSV file for use into a separate database.  However the code that sends the attachment doesn't work, but the system stores the file into a separate folder (I must stress this is while I am testing).

My question is, can I both create the CSV file and send it via email?  If so, what do I need to do?

I am also aware that there are security risks:  One suggestion has been to store the CSV files outside to root directory.  is this foolproof and if not, could anyone make any recommendations?

My code is:

```
<?php

$_POST['password'] = md5($_POST['password']);

$headers=array_keys($_POST);

$file = "csv/" . $_POST['username'].date('Ymdhis').".csv"; //filename

$file = fopen($file, 'a');
fputcsv($file, $headers);
fputcsv($file, $_POST);
fclose($file);

require_once('email/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$m = new PHPMailer;

$m->isSMTP();
$m->SMTPAuth = true;
$m->SMTPDebug = 0;

$m->Host = 'mymail.com';
$m->Username = 'me@mymail.com';
$m->Password = 'mypass';
$m->SMTPSecure = 'SSL';
$m->Port = 26;

$m->From = 'me@mymail.com';
$m->FromName = 'My name';
$m->addReplyTo('me@mymail.com', 'Reply Address'); 
$m->AddAddress('me@mymail.com', 'My name');

$m->isHTML(true);

$m->addAttachment('csv/data.csv', 'data.csv');

$m->Subject = 'New feed ';
$m->Body = '<p>This is an email just sent from our website</p><p><strong>Please import into your database.</strong></p>';
$m->AltBody = 'This is the body.  Please import into the database';

if($m->send()) {
echo '<h1>Thank you</h1>  <p>We have received your Registration and will send you confirmation details shortly.</p>';

} else {
  echo $m->ErrorInfo;
}
```

I also have a checkbox field that needs to be written with the commas separating the values, for example 1,2,3.  How can I write this?

Any assistance/advice will as always be gratefully received.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens when you run this file?

Comment: If someone suggested you try [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php), have you read the docs and experimented with it?

Comment: are you sure you don't need a database? have you thought about this or you just do what random people here tell you ?

Comment: I see a lot of security risks here. If I knew a website that saves there data ( even passwords ) like this I would post it online and see them being publicly destroyed. No just kidding, i'm not that kind of a person. **But many are!!**

Comment: Meda and Vissar it is for a separate site, but I am always open to suggestions.

Comment: @S.Visser Sorry I am open to suggestions

Comment: @WillHarrison the previous step is an enquiry form which is processed by this script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$_POST['id']="101";                               //example data
$_POST['username']="kraysak";                     //example data
$_POST['password']="grumpycat";                   //example data
$_POST['usergroup']="admin";                      //example data
$_POST['lastaccess']="14-10-2014 00:01";          //example data, 

$_POST['password'] = md5($_POST['password']);

$headers=array_keys($_POST);

$file = $_POST['username'].date('Ymdhis').".csv"; //filename

$file = fopen($file, 'a');
fputcsv($file, $headers ); //write headers (key of the $_POST array (id,username,password,etc)
fputcsv($file, $_POST );
fclose($file);
```

this create a file named `kraysak20141014010253.csv` with the next information:

```
id,username,password,usergroup,lastaccess
101,kraysak,5557981401e83c1963412f19c7487965,amdin,"14-10-2014 00:01"
```

is hard for me to explain, (my english isn't good enought) but fputcsv funtion write the content of an array in the file, and $_POST is an array... so, you dont need to create new variables, you only need to use md5() function in one variable.

Comment: This works, but how can I remove the headers being listed? 

--This row-- id,username,password,usergroup,lastaccess
101,kraysak,5557981401e83c1963412f19c7487965,amdin,"14-10-2014 00:01"

Comment: It does operate without $headers but I get an error_log file with a couple of PHP warnings.

Answer (score 0):

fputcsv consists of two parameters; location and content.  So;

```
fputcsv(location, content);
```

or

```
$fileNameVariable = 'blah';
$fileName = $fileNameVariable . date('Ymdhis') . '.csv';
$fp = fopen('/exampleDirectoryName/' . $fileName, 'w');
$headers = array ('info1', 'info2', 'info3');
fputcsv($fp, $headers);
```

You can adapt this exmaple for your situation pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$csvname=md5(rand());
$fp = fopen("csv/$csvname.csv", "w");
$savearray = [ $name, $email, $password, $usergroup, $lastsid, $fname, $lname, $lastaccess, $company, $phone, $addone, $addtwo, $city, $stateprov, $country, $postalcode, $rescom, $addbook, $subscriptions, $affilid, $affilcommpct, $affilsalestodate, $affilcommearned, $affilcommowed, $affilcommpaid, $whlsalepct, $show_currency, $loyaltypoints ];
fputcsv($fp, $savearray);
fclose($fp);
```

Use `array()` on `$savearray` instead of `[]` for older php versions.

Comment: Thanks @toster-cx.  That works but how do I call the new filename to send as the attachment?

Comment: But if I complete the form with a comma, it breaks and nothing gets sent.